# How to get value from PHP file and insert it into the index.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to get value from PHP file and insert it into the index.php

here is my files:

**image.php**

```
<?php

$client_id = "xxxxxx";

$image ='https://pic.jpg';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Client-ID ' .$client_id ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'image' => $image ));

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$reply = json_decode($reply);
$newimgurl = $reply->data->link;

echo $newimgurl;
```

**index.php**

```
<?php echo $newimgurl; ?>
```

i can get the value if the all above codes in the same file(index.php)

but i want to get *$newimgurl* from image.php to index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index.php write

```
<?php
   include_once "image.php";
   echo $newimgurl;
```

After image.php is include you will have access to variables assigned in image.php file.

You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

You can also change this line `echo $newimgurl;` to `return $newimgurl;` and in index.php  `echo include "image.php";`

Answer (score 0):

Simply call the php file via SRC attribute of IMG tag:

```
<img src="image.php" />
```

Or get the content via PHP using file_get_contents

```
$url = file_get_contents("image.php");
```

EDIT:

can you include "image.php" inside index.php?

```
<?php
    include_once("image.php")
?>
```

Comment: $newimgurl = file_get_contents("image.php"); i used this code but i'm not getting the newimgurl value

Comment: its getting all image.php file code not just $newimgurl

Comment: what about including "image.php" in index.php? I edited the answer

Comment: i want to get the value via AJAX post

Comment: like this $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'image.php',
                            data: {},
                            success: function(data) {})

Comment: if you call the page that way, your var "data" will be filled with binary data representing the image. is that what you want to accomplish?

Comment: can you please give an example to get data from php file?